# I want to see what is in an address in PRIVATE MEMORY of a process

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, sudo

I wonder if I can see the content(pages) of memory address that is suposed to be both MAP_PRIVATE and MAP_ANONYMOUS

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in linux we can run some codes as processes".

Comment: I recall seeing someone getting permission to run a command on shell when they typed the path of a bin before the command a few months ago

Comment: You'll need to be far more specific. As it stands, it's not clear at all what you're asking about.

Comment: fair enough I'll remove the first part of the question, what I want is pretty clear tho

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you may be able to either modify the behavior of the process to reveal the information you want (the code itself, or something like an LD_PRELOAD) or you may be able to do ptrace debugging with gdb or some other tool or something semi-custom using ptrace() directly or via some library.